# How do I restore stock firmware [or] CyanogenMod to a Samsung Galaxy S4 (AT&T) displaying the following firmware error message in recovery mode:

Tags: android, root, samsung-mobile, firmware

"Firmware upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies & try again." This message is prominently displayed underneath a "device to PC connection" graphic. On the top left of the screen, the following information is displayed:

ODIN MODE
Product Name: SGH-1337
Current Binary: Samsung Official
System Status: Custom
Knox Kernel Lock: 0x0
Knox Warranty Void 0x1
CSB-CONFIG-LSB: 0x30
WRITE PROTECTION: Enable
EMMC Burst Mode: Enabled

I have tried using Kies v.2.6, as well as v.3. Neither of them detect the phone. I downloaded Odin and a Samsung S4 firmware image, and attempted to flash it, but received a FAIL error towards the end. However, with so many versions of Odin, as well as the firmware builds available, not to mention the options and toggles available within Odin, I have no way of knowing if I'm doing this correctly.

I require very specific directions on where to obtain each component, and exactly how to go about restoring this device. Thank you.

(My first priority is to get the phone back to it's original running condition. However, if I am able to somehow circumvent this step and install a CyanogenMod (nightly build), I would prefer that, instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My original intention was to unlock and install Cyanogenmod 12.1 on a locked AT&T Samsung Galaxy S4 (SGH-I337). This resulted in a soft-bricking of the device. Fortunately, I was able to restore the device using the following method:

**STEP 1:**
Get your phone into "Download Mode." This is done by turning the phone off and turning it on by pressing the "Volume Down key, Home button, and the Power button, at the same time. You will be shown a screen which will read: "Warning!! A custom OS can cause..." Press the "Volume Up" key to continue onto "Download Mode."

**STEP 2:**
Download the AT&T Galaxy S4 Stock Firmware - SGH-i337 
from: http://galaxys4root.com/galaxy-s4-stock-firmware/
You will see 3 versions. Download this one: AT&T Galaxy S4 SGH-I337 UCUFNB1 (Android 4.4.2)
Extract the contents of this zip file into a temporary folder.

**STEP 3:**
Download Odin v.3.10 (or higher) from http://odin.website. (avoid Odindownload.com - That site has malware on it) Extract the contents of this into the same folder in which you placed the firmware from step 2.

**STEP 4:**
Launch Odin and connect the phone to PC via USB cable. The ID:COM section in Odin will light up once it identifies the connection to your phone.

**STEP 5:** 
Click on the AP button in Odin and select the MD5 file you extracted from the firmware package you downloaded. In the options area, only Auto-Root and F. Reset Time should be selected by default.

**STEP 6.** In Odin, click on the Start button. THe process should take anywhere from 10-15 minutes and you will be shown a progress bar, and finally, a "PASS." notification within Odin. Allow the device to reboot on it's own.

This should restore the phone to it's original factory settings.

Comment: I wrote a similar guide on how to do it on Linux (and OSX and Windows) using heimdall here: https://www.simernes.com/?p=279

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same situation and was able to get back to a base level using Heimdall on Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2.

I have used Heimdall to flash firmware to my Galaxy S4 before, but I ran into problems more recently getting it installed on El Capitan. I had to get the signed patch that is available in this thread https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/issues/291.  I found some good Heimdall basics and insights [here at xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2118100) and [here at kossboss](http://ram.kossboss.com/how-to-use-heimdall-specifically-on-samsung-captivate-download-512-513-and-803-pit-files/).

I followed the steps below from xda (but using Heimdall instead of ODIN): [HOW TO GET TO ANY KITKAT 4.4.2 (NB1, NC1, NI1) OR 4.4.4 (NJ4, NJ5) BASE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s4-att/general/guide-odin-to-stock-updating-rooting-t2926642). In my case, I wanted to just get the phone up again, so I chose NB1...

1. Power off phone
2. Boot into Download Mode
   --- press and hold BOTH power and volume down buttons
   --- when you see "Warning!" screen... release both buttons
   --- press volume up to continue
3. Connect phone to PC via usb cable
   on pc...
4. Extract .tar.md5 from Stock NB1 OTA file

   - *(NOTE): Here I used [unrar](http://www.techradar.com/us/how-to/computing/apple/terminal-101-extracting-rar-files-1305669) to extract the tar.md5. Then, I removed the .md5 extension and extracted the tar contents. There were 15 files.*
5. <strike>Right click Odin and run "as administrator"</strike>
6. Click AP button and select extracted tar.md5 file
7. Click Start

Instead of ODIN for steps 5 - 7, I used Heimdall as follows in three passes of flashing and rebooting to Download mode (see step 2 above).

```
heimdall flash --RECOVERY recovery.img --HIDDEN hidden.img.ext4 --BOOT boot.img
heimdall flash --APNHLOS NON-HLOS.bin --ABOOT aboot.mbn --MDM modem.bin --RPM rpm.mbn --SBL1 sbl1.mbn --SBL2 sbl2.mbn --SBL3 sbl3.mbn --PERSDATA persdata.img.ext4 --TZ tz.mbn --CACHE cache.img.ext4
heimdall flash --SYSTEM system.img.ext4
```

I happened to experience intermittent USB errors (`libusbx: error [submit_bulk_transfer] bulk transfer failed (dir = In): no connection to an IOService (code = 0xe00002c0)`) during several attempts.  By trial and error, I noticed that the errors were more common on the large system.img.ext4 file and had moved it to the final pass.  By flashing the recovery and boot partitions first, I noticed the benefit of bringing online the firmware recovery process, which could open up some additional possible alternatives like ADB sideloading.  Absent of any issues, I believe the flashing could be done in one pass, but I haven't confirmed.

It is important to note that the `libusbx` errors that I was getting was resolved by moving my USB cable to a different port on my MacBook Pro.  I had read to check the cable and switch ports in other situtations, and after seeing the intermittent failures, this seemed to be the trick that allowed me to successfully flash the large system file without error and ultimately get the phone running.